# Memory layout of a set

Tags: delphi, casting, set, delphi-2009

How is a `set` organized in memory in Delphi?

What I try to do is casting a simple type to a set type like

```
var
  MyNumber : Word;
  ShiftState : TShiftState;
begin
  MyNumber:=42;
  ShiftState:=TShiftState(MyNumber);
end;
```

Delphi (2009) won't allow this and I don't understand why. It would make my life a lot easier in cases where I get a number where single bits encode different enum values and I just could cast it like this. Can this be done?

One approach I was going to go for is:

```
var
  ShiftState : TShiftState;
  MyNumber : Word absolute ShiftState;
begin
  MyNumber:=42;
end;
```

But before doing this I thought I'd ask for the memory layout. It's more a feeling than knowlege what I am having right now about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Delphi set is a bit field who's bits correspond to the associated values of the elements in your set. For a set of normal enumerated types the bit layout is straight-forward:

- bit 0 corresponds to set element with ordinal value 0
- bit 1 corresponds to set element with ordinal value 1
- and so on.

Things get a bit interesting when you're dealing with a non-contiguous set or with a set that doesn't start at 0. You can do that using Delphi's subrange type (example: `set of 3..7`) or using enumerated types that specify the actual ordinal value for the elements:

```
type enum=(seven=7, eight=8, eleven=11); 
EnumSet = set of enum;
```

In such cases Delphi will allocate the minimum required amount of bytes that will include all required bits, but will not "shift" bit values to use less space. In the `EnumSet` example Delphi will use two bytes:

- The first byte will have it's 7th bit associated with `seven`
- The second byte will have bit 0 associated with `eight`
- The second byte will have bit 3 associated with `eleven`

You can see some tests I did over here: [Delphi 2009 - Bug? Adding supposedly invalid values to a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839745/delphi-2009-bug-adding-supposedly-invalid-values-to-a-set/4842902#4842902)

Tests were done using Delphi 2010, didn't repeat them for Delphi XE.

Comment: Cosmin, thanks very much for summing it up! I also very much enjoyed reading about your tests in the linked post and recommend everybody to read it! Now everything is clear and me and the compiler are happy :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a correctly sized ordinal type. For me (D2007) your code compiles with `MyNumber: Byte`:

```
procedure Test;
var
  MyNumber: Byte;
  ShiftState: TShiftState;
begin
  MyNumber := 42;
  ShiftState := TShiftState(MyNumber);
end;
```

I have used this technique in some situations and didn't encounter problems.

---

**UPDATE**

The `TShiftState` type has been extended since Delphi 2010 to include two new states, `ssTouch` and `ssPen`, based on the [corresponding doc page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Classes) ([current doc page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TShiftState)). The [Delphi 2009 doc](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TShiftState.html) still has `TShiftState` defined as a set of 7 states.

So, your attempt to convert `Word` to `TShiftState` would work in Delphi 2010+, but `Byte` is the right size for Delphi 2009.

Comment: Thanks for this nudge in the right direction! I searched further and found my answer in another thread. By the way: in Delphi XE the `TShiftState` contains 9 members, so I think there we would have to make `MyNumber` a `Word`, not a `Byte` anymore.

Comment: @Heinrich: I kept this page open without refreshing it for too long and didn't see your comment. So it appeared you found the explanation before I did. Still, I think my update won't harm Ulrich's answer. :)

Comment: @Andriy The more information the better. May nobody be ever confused again by the memory layout of sets :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I just now stumbled upon the following question: [Delphi 2009 - Bug? Adding supposedly invalid values to a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839745/delphi-2009-bug-adding-supposedly-invalid-values-to-a-set)

The accepted answer of Cosmin contains a very detailed description of what is going on with sets in Delphi. And why I better not used my approach with `absolute`. Apparently a set variable can take from 1 to 32 byte of memory, depending on the enum values.

Comment: You should use something like {$IF SizeOf(set_in_question) <> SizeOf(typecast_var)}{$MESSAGE ERROR}

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

For <= 8 elements, PByte(@MyNumber)^, for <= 16 elements, PWord(@MyNumber)^, etc.

If the enum takes up more space (through the min enum size compiler option) this will still work.

Comment: I'd go for `Byte(MyEnumVar)` etc and have the added compiler checks. One can write a pair of functions `OrdToMyEnum` and back to centralize the casts. So you have only one place to change if the enum type ever should increase to the "next" size.